# Use variables declared inside do-while loop in the condition

Tags: c++, do-while

I was writing something like this code:

```
do {
    int i = 0;
    int j = i * 2;
    cout<<j;

    i++;
} while (j < 100);
```

(http://codepad.org/n5ym7J5w)

and I was surprised when my compiler told me that I cannot use the variable 'j' because it is not declared outside the do-while loop.

I am just curious about if there is any technical reason why this cant be possible.

Comment: `double` is a keyword, and yes, `double` (the variable) is not in scope outside the loop (thus can't be used as the condition);

Comment: Sorry about using double as a variable name. lol. It is edited now

Comment: variable can not have name double because its keyword

Comment: Do you still get the same compile error after renaming `double` to `j`? Also, please post the error verbatim.

Comment: This code is pretty much equivalent to `for(;;) {cout << 0;}`

Comment: @chris Yes, if it compiled at all in the first place (`j` scope issue).

Comment: @syam, Yeah, just fixing that gives you my code.

Comment: The "technical reason" is that it makes absolutely no sense to use a variable in a condition that you're going to reset and reinitialize every time you enter the loop.

Comment: @Crowman It does make sense.  If it's just a bool, and you set the variable in all iterations, then it should be usable in the condition, if the compiler allowed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a reason why this can't be possible.  It is due to the limitation of "statement-scope".

Your variables i and j have been declared with "local scope" -- that is variables inside {} brackets.  You actually wanted j to be declared with "statement scope" but this is not possible.

Statement-scope are those variables declared as part of 'for', 'while', 'if' or 'switch' statements.  Statement scope does not cover do-while statements, though, which is why you cannot do this.

You have basically exposed a language drawback of using do-while.

It would be better if the language offered:

```
do {
.
.
.
} while (int j < 100);
```

but it does not offer this.

Answer (score 13):

The scope of `j` is just within the `{}` braces.  You can't use it in the loop condition, which is outside that scope.

From a C++ draft standard I have handy:

> A name declared in a block is local to that block. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration and ends at the end of its declarative region.

A "block" is also known as a "compound statement", and is a set of statements enclosed in braces `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Double, which must be changed to an unreserved word (thanks Chad), needs to be declared outside the do's scope in order to be used in the while condition.

```
int i = 0;
int d = 0;
do{
    d = i * 2;
    cout << d;
    i++;
} while (d < 100);
```

Comment: You _would_ change the name of `double` if you wanted it to _compile_.

Answer (score 0):

- The syntax for do loop is do{ } any variable declaration within the { } will only exist within this scope. Therefore the scope of j is only within do{ } because it was declared within this scope. It can only be called or referenced within this scope.
- If you want to access j outside this scope, you need to declare j as global variable. Move the declaration of j outside this scope.

Answer (score -1):

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0;j < 100;++i){
j = i * 2;
cout<<j;
}
```

before every loop set i = 0; and declarate as int + for loop works better

Comment: Care to explain? Code without explanations is not acceptable on SO. Also, please indent. -1

Comment: im bad english, just i try to help and getting -1 realy...

Comment: Yes -1 because you didn't provide any explanation. It doesn't matter if your english is not very good, but please try at least. How are we supposed to understand what you mean if you just give code and no explanation at all? I know this seems harsh but this is how we keep improving both SO and ourselves.

Comment: No problem, just remember that my vote was not against **you** but just against this one **message**. I removed it, because you tried. ;)