# Error in Xcode: Reference to overloaded function could not be referenced

Tags: c++

number of grades a user inputs. I am working with dynamic array allocation. I feel confident in my code, but Xcode is giving me an error in my sort function.I thought that I was doing it right, but apparently something is wrong, and I'm not entirely sure where. I am still trying to figure out dynamic memory allocation, so I'm sure that's where my error is generating from, I just don't know where the cause is.  Here is my full program:

```
// This program demonstrates the use of dynamic arrays
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void sort(float *score[], int numOfScores);

int main()
{
float  *scores;
int    total = 0;
float  average;
float  numOfScores;
int    count;

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

cout << "Enter the number of scores to be averaged and sorted.";
cin >> numOfScores;


scores = new float(numOfScores);

for ( count = 0; count < numOfScores;  count++)
{
    cout << "Please enter a score:" << endl;
    cin >> scores[count];         }

for (count = 0; count < numOfScores; count++)
{
    total = total + scores[count];
}

average = total / numOfScores;

cout << "The average score is " << average << endl;

sort(*scores, numOfScores);

delete [] scores;
return 0;
}

//*******************************************
//              Sort Function
// Bubble sort is used to sort the scores
//*******************************************
void sort(float *score[], int numOfScores)
{
   do
{
    bool swap = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < (numOfScores -1); count++)
    {
        if (*score[count] > *score[count+1])
        {
            float *temp = score[count];
            score[count] = score[count+1];
            score[count+1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
}while(swap); //This is where I'm receiving the error. 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `scores = new float(numOfScores);` I seriously doubt that does what you think it does. Pretty sure you wanted `scores = new float[numOfScores];`. And `float *score[]` is certainly not correct for your parameter type. You want `float score[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use variables declared inside do-while loop in the condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541304/use-variables-declared-inside-do-while-loop-in-the-condition)

Comment: That fixed that error message, but now I'm getting an error message related to "algorithm." I even tried taking out `#include <algorithm>` and I still get an error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`swap` is local to the `do...while` loop so it cannot be used in the while condition.  One would expect an error related to that but since you have `using namespace std;` and `#include <algorithm>` you have now introduced the `std::swap` function into the scope of the program

```
while(swap);
```

Is trying to convert `std::swap` to a function pointer but it can't as it is overloaded and it does not know which overload to use.

For further reading on why to avoid using `using namespace std;` see: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)